# Problem getting custom date format for plotting purposes

Tags: r, datetime

I want to use ggplot to plot time series over several years with the date in the format 'MMM YYYY' on the x axis and chronologically sorted.

To date I have extracted the dates required into a character variable but when plotted the months/years as sorted alphabetically instead of chronologically - I understand why that is the case. 
So I have tried to coerce the variable to a date (in format MMM YYYY) and have tried every conceivable permutation of the as.Date formatting to no avail. The  code I am using is ...

```
df <- data.frame(c("16:45 11-Nov-17", "22:30 11-Jul-18", "01:24 30-Dec-18", "12:41 12-Jan-19", "13:13 11-Feb-19", "15:22 05-May-19"))
                 names(df) <- c("TDate")

Data <- mutate(df, Date = parse_date_time(df$TDate, "HM:dmy"),
                   MthY = as.Date(paste0(month(ymd_hms(Date), label = TRUE), " ", year(ymd_hms(Date))), format = "%b %Y"))
```

The code doesn't generate any error messages but fails to render the Month/Year (MthY)

-# A tibble: -6 x 3
 TDate               Date               MthY
                              
   1 16:45 11-Nov-17 2017-11-11 16:45:00 NA
   2 22:30 11-Jul-18 2018-07-11 22:30:00 NA
   3 01:24 30-Dec-18 2018-12-30 01:24:00 NA
   4 12:41 12-Jan-19 2019-01-12 12:41:00 NA
   5 13:13 11-Feb-19 2019-02-11 13:13:00 NA
   6 15:22 05-May-19 2019-05-05 15:22:00 NA

Does anyone have any thoughts on this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get hold of the formats in `?strptime`, you can convert it easily

```
format(as.POSIXct(df$TDate, format = "%H:%M %d-%b-%y"), "%b %Y")
#[1] "Nov 2017" "Jul 2018" "Dec 2018" "Jan 2019" "Feb 2019" "May 2019"
```

To add it in the `dplyr` chain

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(MthY = format(as.POSIXct(TDate, format = "%H:%M %d-%b-%y"), "%b %Y"))

#            TDate     MthY
#1 16:45 11-Nov-17 Nov 2017
#2 22:30 11-Jul-18 Jul 2018
#3 01:24 30-Dec-18 Dec 2018
#4 12:41 12-Jan-19 Jan 2019
#5 13:13 11-Feb-19 Feb 2019
#6 15:22 05-May-19 May 2019
```

Comment: Of Course !! - Can't imagine why I was messing around with paste0; this is so much more elegant :-) Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anytime` and add the format (`addFormats`) if the format is not already present with `getFormats`

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)
addFormats("%H:%M %d-%b-%y")
df %>%
    mutate(MthY = format(anytime(TDate), "%b %Y"))
#           TDate     MthY
#1 16:45 11-Nov-17 Nov 2017
#2 22:30 11-Jul-18 Jul 2018
#3 01:24 30-Dec-18 Dec 2018
#4 12:41 12-Jan-19 Jan 2019
#5 13:13 11-Feb-19 Feb 2019
#6 15:22 05-May-19 May 2019
```